# Regex to match sentence with decimals and names

Tags: c#, regex

I feel like I'm pretty close with this one but as soon as I move the punctuation capture to the end of the sentence it misscaptures.

The sentence scenarios are below:

```
This is a sentence with a name like Mr. D. Smith and Mr J. Smith in it. This is a  sentence      with odd   spacing. This is one with lots of exclamation marks at the end!!!!This is another with a decimal 10.00 in the middle. Why is it so hard to find sentence endings?Last sentence without a space at the start.
```

This should result in captures of:

```
This is a sentence with a name like Mr. D. Smith and Mr J. Smith in it. 
This is a  sentence      with odd   spacing. 
This is one with lots of exclamation marks at the end!!!!
This is another with a decimal 10.00 in the middle. 
Why is it so hard to find sentence endings?
Last sentence without a space at the start.
```

This is the expression as I have it:

```
.*?(?:[!?.;]+)((?<!(Mr|Mrs|Dr|Rev).?)(?=\D|\s+|$)(?:[^!?.;\d]|\d*\.?\d+)*)(?=(?:[!?.;]+))
```

There are two problems as it stands:

1. The punctuation is at the start
2. It correctly handles one name per sentence but not two (for bonus points I'd like it to correctly capture "Mr D. J. Smith" but I can't work out how it wouldn't match sentences ending with a single letter.

The data going into this will be somewhat normalised so we know that it will end in a full stop and be on a single line but any pointers welcome.

Comment: A natural language parser in regex? I can safely say that you will never write a regex that encapsulates all punctuation rules. Think again.

Comment: We've got an NLP step before this so that was the other thought (passing in exceptions) cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @spender that using a parser is recommended to do this to filter all punctuation rules.

However, the following will work for your scenarios.

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(s, @"(.*?(?<!(?:\b[A-Z]|Mrs?|Dr|Rev|\d))[!?.;]+)\s*"))
         Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

**Output**

```
This is a sentence with a name like Mr. D. Smith and Mr J. Smith in it. 
This is a  sentence      with odd   spacing. 
This is one with lots of exclamation marks at the end!!!!
This is another with a decimal 10.00 in the middle. 
Why is it so hard to find sentence endings?
Last sentence without a space at the start.
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/OAjgxv)

Comment: Perfect thanks hwnd, we'll pre-process the input first with the natural language parser (or more to the point our named entity parser) and will resolve any "names" in the sentences before it hits this but your solution sorts the punctuation thanks.